# Sort by field in ForeignKey model

Tags: python, django

I have created a Django model called Person, which has got a 'user' ForeignKey to django.contrib.auth.models.User

How can I set the ordering on class Person to self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name?

Comment: I can do this in a queryset by doing this:

Person.objects.order_by('user__first_name', 'user__last_name')

But how can I set the default ordering on the Person model to be user.first_name and user.last_name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ['user__first_name', 'user__last_name']
```

Should do the trick iirc